# Windows Server 2012 R2 Known credentials are rejected

Tags: passwords, windows-server-2012-r2, user

I got a call from a business that I do I.T. support for, saying that they couldn't connect to their server's software or shares.  When I arrived to check it out, I found that the user names and passwords that I set up on the server were being rejected.  I started up the server again, and was able to log in with the credentials I had tried moments ago.

What would cause this kind of error?  What specifically should I be looking for in Event Viewer, or any other diagnostic program?

Answer (score 0):

In what way are they being rejected?

Are they locked? Go to the account settings and see if they are locked

Do they have the right to access the computer? Do they have a logon hours?

for user authentication in the event viewer you go to Windows logs -> security.

Comment: They were being rejected when I tried to log into the server.  First I tried to open a share, typed in the Administrator password, and it didn't work.  Next I tried to remote into the server, and was told the user name/password didn't work.  Then I tried to log in at the physical location, and was told the user name and password.

No, there are no disabled user accounts.  They do have rights to access the shares, and no logon hours are set.

Thanks, I will check those logs now.